# String implicit conversion operators to const char*/wchar_t *

Tags: c++, stl

I find MFC/ATL `CString` class very convenient in Win32 C++ code; in particular I found convenient the fact that we can pass instances of `CString` to Win32 API's `LPCWSTR` (i.e. `const wchar_t *`) parameters directly, thanks to implicit conversion operator defined by `CString`.

Instead, when using `std::wstring`, an explicit call to `.c_str()` method is required.

So, why do the STL string classes (both `std::string` and `std::wstring`) require an explicit method call (`c_str()`) instead of defining an implicit `const char*`/`const wchar_t *` conversion operator?

Are there serious pitfalls hidden with implicit conversion operators?

Comment: How about undesirable conversion to `bool`? More pragmatically, if you're writing standard C++, you shouldn't be having those naked pointers, so perhaps it wasn't felt necessary to provide that much convenience purely for foreign interfaces.

Comment: `std::string` is already constructible from `char const*`. Having the former then implicitly convert back to the latter would be .. horrid. I can't explain why; it just would be.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Maybe another undesirable thing is: CString s; ...; delete s; // BOOM.

Comment: Questions like these are answered in "The Design and Evolution of C++" by Stroustrup. It's an oldish book but answers ton of "why?" questions about C++.

Comment: Mr_C64: Quite sure that won't count - but even then, I wouldn't see that as a valid reason, as you could just use `&` and achieve the same thing.

Comment: @Mario: this doesn't make much sense to me... You can use & with every class instance, that's not the point. The problem is that an implicit pointer conversion can shut down the compiler which would instead emit an error if it encounters "X x; delete x;".

Comment: Okay, as in hiding a coding mistake you'd notice otherwise (not something you do on purpose).

Comment: My previous comment typo: "shut down" should be "shut up". Sorry.

Comment: @Mario: but it's better when the errors happen at compile-time than at run-time :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [why doesn't std::string provide implicit conversion to char*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492061/why-doesnt-stdstring-provide-implicit-conversion-to-char)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever the theoretical concerns are, I will only note that in years of working with CString I've never been bitten by this feature. The convenience far outweighs the dangers.

Comment: me, too :) I was curious, so this is why I asked here.

Comment: @Mr_C64, I'm quite surprised that this hasn't gotten an answer yet that directly answers the question. I posted this to represent the opposing viewpoint, I didn't expect it to be the *only* viewpoint.