# What is `CString`?

Tags: c++, string, mfc

Why do I see some code using `CStrings` declared differently.

Some use this format

```
char a_c_string [];
```

While others use

```
CString another_c_string;
```

Is there a difference? All the references I have found on `CStrings` declare it as I did in the first example, I have only seen it done the other way on forums and the like where people are giving examples.

Comment: CString is a Microsoft abomination, no ?

Comment: `CString` does not exist in any language I've ever used. Where did it come from? Please choose one of C or C++ (then tag as such), then tell us which language `CString` is in (then tag as such).

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel [CString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300688(v=vs.60).aspx) is an MFC concept

Comment: @acraig5075: It would be great if Microsoft could make this fact clearer in their documentation. They have a nasty habit of blurring the line between C++ and "what they want C++ to be"

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel It's simply part of a gui framework. Are Qt blurring the lines with QString and are wxWindows blurring the lines with wxString?

Comment: @acraig5075: They both make it pretty clear.

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel: you'd better to stop travelling time and resort the history sequence in you mind. CString existed far before std::string was invented and C++ was even standardized. Don't bash with no reason.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: Irrelevant. The documentation exists now, and there have been _twenty years_ to clarify what is and is not standard.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`CString` is neither a C nor a C++ type. [It appears to be a Microsoft invention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300688%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) that is essentially an alternative to `std::string`:

> - `CString` objects can grow as a result of concatenation operations.
> - `CString` objects follow "value semantics." Think of a `CString` object as an actual string, not as a pointer to a string.
> - You can freely substitute `CString` objects for `const char*` and `LPCTSTR` function arguments.
> - A conversion operator gives direct access to the string's characters as a read-only array of characters (a C-style string).

I recommend ignoring it, so that:

(a) people know what you are talking about;
(b) your code is portable;
(c) you are writing C++ that everybody can rationalise about according to the worldwide-accepted ISO C++ standard that many, many people spend many, many hours arguing about for this express purpose (y'know, as opposed to a few guys in a room in *one company's office*).

It will only be available when you are programming with *Microsoft Visual C++*, which is substantially limiting.

Comment: On the positive side, `std::string` does all these things, except converting to `const char *`/`LPCSTLSKJ`, for which you simply call `my_str.c_str()`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: And [it's actually a _good_ thing that this is not implicit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492061/why-doesnt-stdstring-provide-implicit-conversion-to-char). No surprise, however, that Microsoft decided to break the convention on that one; that's rather their MO, innit.

Comment: As I only run Linux and don't have access to Visual C++ it's of little use to me, but I just saw it in quite a few code examples while researching string processing in c/c++ and the merits of using cstring vs string object. Thank you for the reply

Comment: It does not "appears to be". It **IS** an MS invention that's part of the MFC library, invented to wrap Win16 and 32 APIs even before the C++ standard was established. It exist still today since it is granted to map the OS API (unlike std::string, that use CRT for its own functions). Today there is most likely no need, but programs that are not targeted to be multiplatform take some advantages from that.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: "is" leads to "appears to be", by simple cause and effect. :) You'll find that my wording was chosed based upon my own lack of familiarity with MFC, rather than to imply that `CString` somehow only half-exists!

Answer (score 29):

Many GUI frameworks have their own string class.
e.g. QT has the [QString](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qstring.html), wxWindows has [wxString](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxString). In this case MFC has the [CString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class), (along with other convenience containers like CArray, CList, CMap, etc.).
It's then convenient and makes sense to use CString when in the context of MFC gui code because then you're already heavily dependent on Visual C++ and code portability will not be envisaged. I'd be careful of blanket statements saying to ignore it because it's non-standard - it all depends on the context.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the "C" in "`CString`" stands for "Class".

Answer (score 15):

Just in case that's the cause of confusion: The "C" in "CString" is just a prefix that all classes from the MFC have. The MFC is a C++ library by Microsoft wrapping the win32 API. This string class has little to do with "C strings", which is used to describe the string-handling facilities that the C language provides. The C language only provides functions for string handling that operate on a pointer to the char array representing the string and they require that the last character is a NUL (aka NUL-terminated or zero-terminated). Note that C++ itself also has a string class `std::string` (well, actually there's also `std::wstring` and both are specializations of the `std::basic_string` template, but as a beginner you can safely ignore those).

Comment: Yup, important point, it's quite confusing `CString` and "C-string". It can be *even more* confusing, because `std::string::c_str()` returns "C-string" **but** it *can* be assigned to `CString` (whereas `std::string` cannot).