# Why do I only display one character when I store a string in a char?

Tags: c++

[Im making a random word generator, so i use time.h library to use srand and generate a random number... If random number = 0, then char (principal)= 'hola'.
But in CMD only shows the final character :( (Sorry for my bad english)

[image]

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int principal;
    char principal1;

    srand(time(NULL));

    principal = rand() % 2;

    if (principal == 0)
    {
        principal1 = 'hola';
        cout << principal1 << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A char is a character. One character. Not a string.

Comment: `std::string principal1;` and `principal1="hola";` Don't forget to put `#include <string>` there.

Comment: You should have gotten compiler warnings about `'hola'`, if you didn't, crank up the compiler warning level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C and C++, a single quote (') means "character" (or one letter/number/symbol). Only one character should be between two single quotes. Example:

```
'c'
'9'
'?'
'\n'  // Newline character
'\0'  // Null character
```

A double quote (") means "string". A string literal (a string you typed into the code between quotes) will be treated as an array of characters with a null character added on the end. This type of character array is called a "c string" (Not to be confused with Microsoft's "[CString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473526/what-is-cstring)".

```
"Hi"  // Same as {'H', 'i', '\0'}
"Hello !\n"  // Same as {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', '!', '\n', '\0'}
```

Trying to put a string inside single quotes is generally not good. It puts you into some [weird territory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459939/what-do-single-quotes-do-in-c-when-used-on-multiple-characters) of implemenation (ie compiler) specific behavior.

If you want to handle the string "hola", then you should use a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) object to store it. (You could use a `char*`, but I recommend using `std::string` until you understand the differences better.)