# Why std::string object could not output correctly when calling CString::Format

Tags: string-formatting

I have written the following statements:

```
   CString strResult;
   std::string errorReason("no this item");
   strResult.Format("the error reason is: %s", errorReason);
```

It seems that it could not format the std::string object correctly; However, if I just replace std::string as CStirng, then strResult could format correctly.

Why `va_arg` could support `CStirng`, instead of `std::string`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `CString`, `std::string` doesn't provide an implicit conversion to `const char*` (for [good reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/492112/471164)) and, what is more important in this case, the binary layout of `std::string` may not be compatible with `const char*`. You should use `errorReason.c_str()` instead.