# Why std::string hasn't const char* cast operator in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stdstring

In C++03, for `std::string` class, `c_str()` and `data()` methods have a different behavior.

The first returns a null-terminated character array and the management of this last is totally dependent from the implementation. Indeed, `c_str()` *could* return a pointer to another pre-allocated buffer, which always contains a null-terminated string, but this is not mandatory. However, the complexity must be constant.

The second one simply returns the pointer to the internal buffer of `std::string`, which could be null-terminated, or not.

Thus, in C++03, you could guess that a cast operator to `const char*` is not a good idea. Indeed, the expected behavior, most of the time, is to have a null-terminated C-style string, but, as the implementation of `c_str()` could vary, there could be an hidden overhead behind the cast operator. In the other case, it could bring confusion if the cast operator returns the same resultat as `data()`.

However, for C++11, `c_str()` and `data()` have the same behavior. `c_str()` returns a pointer to the `std::string` object internal buffer. A cast operator to `const char*` is no more ambiguous. Why this method is not present in `std::string` class in C++11 ?

Thanks !

Comment: Devil's Advocate:  Why should it be?

Comment: Why would we want one? `c_str` or `data` is more readable than an explicit cast and an implicit cast would cause so many problems.

Comment: Because it is a useful method and not just "sugar code" ? Always call `c_str()` when you need a `const char*` is boring. @chris: what kind of problems ?

Comment: Casting operators in general can be a pain in the neck.  Code now won't compile, and if it does compile, unwanted behavior can happen, etc...

Comment: The `char*` you get in **both** C++03 and C++11 is still dependant on the lifetime of the `std::string`.  An implicit cast to `char*` would mean implicit creation of potentially dangling pointers.

Comment: How could the complexity be constant if you need to allocate a new buffer and fill it with the string plus terminator?

Comment: @Deduplicator: this is off-topic ; I haven't said that another buffer is allocated. I have said this is implementation specific.

Comment: every time I've designed a class with implicit cast operator, I've taken it out again after actually trying to use the class

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: So, why not an explicit cast to `const char*` for lvalues?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: In the Qt library, for example, QByteArray has a cast operator to `const char*`, and I do not see what is the problem with that.

Comment: @AntiClimacus - I am in `Matt McNabb`s neighborhood of thinking.  Every class I've seen developed with casting operators winds up doing something unexpected in non-trivial code.  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492061/why-doesnt-stdstring-provide-implicit-conversion-to-char

Comment: If you're asking why it doesn't have an explicit cast operator, it wouldn't have any advantage over `c_str()`. If you're asking why it doesn't have an implicit cast operator, see the link given by @PaulMcKenzie.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is fundamentally about the philosophy behind the design of the `string` class.  I can but opine.

Why should `string` have a cast operator to `const char*`?  Cast operators are syntactic sugar for other operations, and are truly needed only in unusual circumstances.  Really, they are never needed -- you can always accomplish the same goal in another way.

`string` already does provide the means to interract with old C-style interfaces, via `c_str` and `data`.  Adding a cast operator in to the mix doesn't add functionality and does add complexity to the class.  Moreover, using a cast operator is always semantically murky.  In call-site code, a cast such as with `static_cast <const char*>` is generally expected to be a compile-time operation.  By performing this cast through run-time code, you ambiguate your code.  It's not as clear.  Because the expectations and reality aren't the same, it's much easier to misuse this run-time cast than the compile-time equivalent.

I would argue that there should not be an implicit conversion operator anywhere it's not truly needed; and it isn't here.

Comment: I'd also add Drew's point: dangling pointers are encouraged with an implicit conversion. Some STL areas have been designed in order to avoid common pitfalls.

Comment: Where does the OP say the cast operator shall be implicit? Also, there's an easy way to restrict it to non-temporaries.

Comment: @Deduplicator:  Well, I guess he doesn't.  But at the same time he hasn't said it should be explicit.  I still don't see the necessity either way.

Comment: @Deduplicator The problem exists with non-temporaries.  With two lvalues, you still have one dependant on the lifetime of the other.

Comment: @JohnDibling: Thanks. I understand the STL philosophy, but C++ philosophy is also `allowing a useful feature is more important than preventing every possible misuse of C++`, and all your responses are about misuses, dangling pointers, thread safety, etc. These errors could be done with the pointer returned by `c_str()`, too. Furthermore, if it is not a good idea to use a cast operator, because casts are expected to be at compile-time and not at runtime, when could I use a cast operator ? What could be a good case to use it ?

Comment: @AntiClimacus While you can write incorrect code using `c_str()`, **the problem with implicit cast operator is that sometime you won't notice that you got a temporary object if you are not careful enough.** The other problem is that with a class that is much used like `std::string` such a change would also break or change the behavior existing code in some cases.

Comment: @AntiClimacus The philosophy is also changing with years... Newer features are designed to help write correct code but obviously it is almost impossible to fix some major flaws in the language like implicit fallthrough, 0 used as nullptr, declaration/initialization ambiguity...

Comment: I want to add a note here, maybe just as much of a question: std::string does take const char* as a constructor overload. That way it is possible (or even common) to pass in a string like a regular c string to a function/method that takes a std::string (which will create a temporary object in the calling scope) that may well be violate the runtime of the string in the same way as the const char* operator would have.
Doesn't this indicate some kind of hypocrazy in the reasoning here?

Comment: @Larswad: The overload taking `const char*` makes a *new* `std::string` containing a *copy* of the `const char*`'s data. Once constructed, there's no further tie to the `const char*`, so there's no risk of "violating the runtime of the string". The converse, getting the `const char*` from the internals of a `std::string` *does* have that problem; the lifetime of the `const char*` is tied to the `std::string`, but APIs accepting `const char*` have no way to know that; having them silently convert it to `const char*` risks them *storing* it beyond the lifetime of the `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for these changes was thread safety and in particular avoidance of invalidating iterators and references. For this to happen required null terminating buffers.

More can be read on the proposal [N2534](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2534.html).