# TinyXML2 SetAttribute Can't Accept String Object?

Tags: xml, setattribute, tinyxml2

I'm using TinyXML2 and I'm facing an issue with `SetAttribute`.

It accepts a string literal (i.e. `"001"`) but not a string variable.

```cpp
void createDoc(string customerID, string name) {
    XMLDocument doc;
    XMLNode * pRoot = doc.NewElement("containerRequirement");
    doc.InsertFirstChild(pRoot);

    XMLElement * p1Element = doc.NewElement("customer"); // Start customer

    p1Element->SetAttribute("ID", customerID); // not working
    p1Element->SetAttribute("ID", "001");      // working

    XMLElement * p2Element = doc.NewElement("name");
    cout << "NAME is: " << name << endl;
    p2Element->SetText(name);
}
```

Please enlighten me on this issue.

- customerID is not accepted as a String unlike "001" is accepted with no errors. But both CustomerID and "001" are strings, why does this happen?

Comment: Please detail what "not working" means. Include the exact error message you get and the exact value of `customerID`.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see reading *tinyxml2.h*, among the various definitions for *SetAttribute* is:

```
void SetAttribute( const char* name, const char* value )    {
    XMLAttribute* a = FindOrCreateAttribute( name );
    a->SetAttribute( value );
}
```

Consequently, you will need to change your code for *customerID* as follows:

```
 p1Element->SetAttribute("ID", customerID.c_str());
```

where [c_str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) essentially converts an *std::string* to a *char** (see the link for further details). For a discussion of the reason why there is no implicit conversion from *std::string* to *char **, I invite you to read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/492112/3738882).

Hope it helps!