# output vector<T> in template function

Tags: c++, c++11

This section of code gives an error:

```
template <class T>
void print_vector(vector<T>& v, string sep)
{
    std::ostream_iterator<T> ostr_it(std::cout, sep) ;
    std::copy(begin(v), end(v), ostr_it);
}
```

> main.cpp:17:30: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::ostream_iterator<float>'
>      std::ostream_iterator<T> ostr_it(std::cout, sep);

I am confused because if I do it outside the template function and output the vector directly there is no error:

```
vector<float> result(elements);
std::copy(begin(result), end(result), ostream_iterator<float>(cout, ", "));
```

What is wrong? Do I need to specialize each template function?

Comment: `std::ostream_iterator` does not seem to have a constructor taking `string` object. But there is a one that takes `const char*`. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator/ostream_iterator

Comment: Yikes, that works. That seems an omission in the language to me. Explicit conversions?

Comment: @zahir You should post it as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since no answer was posted I guess I'll go ahead.

The signature for `ostream_iterator` accept's a C-string, and not a C++ string:

```
std::ostream_iterator(ostream_type& stream, const CharT* delim)
```

It has been chosen that *implicit cast* to `char *` from `std::string` is not desirable, as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492061/why-doesnt-stdstring-provide-implicit-conversion-to-char), so you get an error.

To make it work, you can simply cast the `std::string` yourself:

```
std::ostream_iterator<T> ostr_it(std::cout, sep);         // DOES NOT WORK
std::ostream_iterator<T> ostr_it(std::cout, sep.c_str()); // WORKS
```

Comment: It would be good to also show some alternative correct code  (I suppose `sep.c_str()`)