# Conversion vs subscript operator overload for class wrapping an array

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, conversion-operator

I have a class wrapping an array and want to provide the typical subscript access to its users.

```
...
class C;
C c;
auto x = c[0];
...
```

I may both provide conversion

```
class C
{
    int i[10];
public:
    operator int*() { return i; }
};
```

and provide subscript operator overload

```
class C
{
    int i[10];
public:    
    int& operator[](unsigned idx) {
        // eventual out-of-bounds check
        return i[idx]; 
    }
};
```

Apart from OOB check, which one should be preferred?

Comment: Prefer `operator[]`. See this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59076004/why-stdstring-does-not-have-const-char-cast) for reasons why.

Comment: _Apart from OOB check_ OOB = out-of-bounds? Range check (maybe, in debug only like in common `std::vector::operator[]` implementations) alone is worth to prefer the latter. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to call `operator[]` on the class `C`, then just overload `operator[]`. Don't allow implicit conversion if not necessary. If you provide `operator int*`, something meaningless and dangerous will be allowed too. e.g.

```
C c;
if (c) ...;
delete c;
```

Comment: _Don't allow implicit conversion if not necessary._ I just remembered how often I add `explicit` to constructors to satisfy my paranoidity, and spent +1. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff It's worthwhile, definitely. :)